# go to .tex file when clicking on a .pdf in includegraphics

Tags: graphics, forward-inverse-search

I am trying to figure out a convenient way to do the following:
I do my presentations in LaTeX and for the sake of compilation time I usually have my graphics in an extra subfolder. While editing the slides it happens from time to time that I have to adjust the pictures as well.

Now my question: Is there any way to tell my latex editor TeXStudio that when I `Shift+Click` on the file in `\includegraphics{graphs\clickme.pdf}` to open the file `graphs\clickme.tex`? I know that this for example is working if you include source code.

Comment: Sumatra as PDF viewer can do this.

Comment: I am looking for a way to do this out of my latex editor, not the pdf viewer.